# Get this element attribute via selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium, and I want to get that 20. Is there any way to do it?
`<div _ngcontent-c12="" class="percentage"><p _ngcontent-c12="">20</p></div>`

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.percentage p").text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.text` or `.get_attribute('innerHTML')`, like this:

```
#1
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.percentage > p').text

#2
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.percentage > p').get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Comment: What if the div doesn't have a class.How can i capture the element using the _ngcontent-c12

Answer (score 1):

The `getText()` applies to any element found with Selenium and retrieves its innerText. You could locate the element via whatever way you want, and then apply the method getText().
Example: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("Insert/Element/XPath/Here").getText()`

Answer (score 1):

Based on your `HTML` code

```
<div _ngcontent-c12="" class="percentage"><p _ngcontent-c12="">20</p></div>
```

You could get the 20 by doing the following `xpath`

```
//div[@class='percentage']//p
```

From there, use that `xpath` to get the text inside of the `paragraph` tag using the following

```
myTwenty = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='percentage']//p").text
```

and you should be good to go.